# How do you remove the "user login" block?

Tags: 7, users

I know this is a simple question, but I've searched for way too long.

I just want to remove the user login box so that all accesses to the site, apart administrator access, will be anonymous. We don't want users to create accounts on the system.

Answer (score 10):

You may disable block on *admin/structure/block* page, but users can create new accounts from */user* page. It's best practice disable creating new accounts by visitors.

- For drupal 7 go to *configuration -> people -> account settings -> registration and cancellation* and set "Who can register accounts?" -> "Administrators only".
- For drupal 6 go to *administer --> user management --> user settings* and set "Public registrations" --> "Only site administrators can create new user accounts."

Comment: This sounds like the right approach but I tried it and the user login block still shows up when I load the site. The changes were definitely saved. Also, if I go into admin/structure/block there is nothing visible called "user login". Any ideas?

Comment: Flush all caches and try load site as anonymous user.

Answer (score 3):

Blocks can be enabled or disabled at the blocks menu item located under the structure menu item. (admin/structure/block)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, my login controls were not adjusted by visiting the "Blocks" page.

Instead, visit your theme's settings page "admin/appearance/settings/[theme name]" and disable the secondary menu

[image]